# How to change which layout is displayed based on user preference?

Tags: android, android-layout

I have an activity ColorChoiceActivity that displays radio group for the user to select a color preference from. I would like to be able to change the xml layout displayed in my PlayGameActivity based on which of these buttons is selected.

Currently I have the PlayGameActivity just display the default layout:

```
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.battlefield_default);
}
```

My ColorChoiceActivity has the following so far:

```
public class ColorChoiceActivity extends Activity {

private RadioGroup radioColorGroup;
private RadioButton radioColorButton;
private Button saveColorBtn;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.color_choice_screen);

    addListenerOnButton();
}

public void addListenerOnButton()
{
    radioColorGroup = (RadioGroup) findViewById(R.id.radioColor);
    saveColorBtn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.saveColorBtn);

    saveColorBtn.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() 
    {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v){
            //get selected radio button from radioGroup
            int selectedId = radioColorGroup.getCheckedRadioButtonId();

            //find the radiobutton by returned id
            radioColorButton = (RadioButton) findViewById(selectedId);

            //change battlefield layout based on selected color
        }
    });
}


}
```

I am not sure how to go about changing the layout displayed in the PlayGameActivity based on what is chosen in ColorChoice. Currently I have several separate battlefield layout files but I don't know how to switch the content view to them based on user choice. Is there a way to do this or am I approaching the problem in the wrong way?

Comment: are u calling the PlayGameActivity on selection of radiobutton?

Comment: No, the PlayGameActivity is called when the user selects a Play Game button on the main menu I've created. The Color Choice screen exists by going from Settings -> Color Choice in my button menus.

Answer (score 0):

In onClick() listner, just remember selected battlefield and then, conditionally set layout using

```
setContentView("your selected layout")
```

in on create method.

Answer (score 0):

Better option is to  use the menu instead of  the radiogroup

```
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item){
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
            case R.id.color1:
            break;
            }
    }
```